# Trying to use Neat, will there be any conflicts using both Bourbon and Compass?

Tags: grid, compass-sass, bourbon, neat

Like the title says, trying to use Neat that requires Bourbon and i'm already deep into using compass. The question is, will there be any complications with similar defined mixins in both Bourbon and Compass for example? Any recommendations on a grid thats not to heavy, where columns are not fixed  and with a MIT license?

Thx people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using features that are exclusive to compass (such as sprites) then you should probably have a look a [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net) instead.

Otherwise, you have every reason to switch to Bourbon and Neat since they are both more lightweight and easier to use.

If you want to use Neat and keep using Compass, you can fork it and copy the few mixins and functions from Bourbon to Neat.

Comment: Good suggestions, I think in this case it would probably be more convenient to copy them even though future updates will have to be manualy configured.